# Undefined variables php

Tags: php

I am working with an api to get the rank of an item in a catalog that is scanned in via csv file. With this came work with an api that i am working with. I got the data to be in an array and prepared to be imported into the API, but when i attempt to reference to variable it give me an error that the variables are undefined. 
Here is some sample code:

```
<?php
//File that has the Variables $groupedArrays defined as an array
for($i = 0; $i < (count($groupedArrays) - 0); $i++){
//Include or require the script since it has to run multiple times.
}
//File that references the variable
$code = $groupedArrays[$i];
?>
```

I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to declare $groupedArrays before starting of the for loop..

Comment: Sadly, in JS your code in the example would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this line in the foreach loop 
`$code = $groupedArrays[$i];`

Thanks.

Comment: On which page would i put the foreach? would the foreach loop look something like this?
    foreach($groupedArrays as $code){
//What is the statement then? $code = $groupedArrays[$i];
}

Comment: No, just put $code = $groupedArrays[$i] inside foreach loop

Comment: Thank you once again! I appreciate the help!

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')' on line 87. Don't i have to put something inside the ()?

Comment: <?php
for($i = 0; $i < (count($groupedArrays) - 0); $i++){
       $code = $groupedArrays[$i];
}
?>

Comment: Then include the external php script?